# Extjs 4. Grid loadData with Pagination

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My grid store has a default `pageSize` property. On the server side I return `totalProperty` parameter. So, pagination is working correctly. But, I've just built a custom filter which is supposed to specify different parameters of the grid, including `pageSize`. And this is not working. In fact, I do not know how to redifine store `pageSize` when using `loadData` function. The whole function which reloads grid looks like this

```
var grid=Ext.getCmp('grid'),
frm=Ext.getCmp('remotefilter').getForm(); // this form contains grid
// parameters which can be redifined by user     
frm.submit({
  url:'../json/grid.php', // this code returns grid data, based on parameters
  submitEmptyText:false,
  success:function(form,action){
    var json=Ext.decode(action.response.responseText,1);
    grid.getStore().loadData(json['items']);
    // I guess, here I should specify new pageSize somehow
    // I can grasp a new value of pageSize from the form above
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

I also tried to do this just before invoking `loadData`:

```
grid.store.pageSize=newlimit;       
Ext.getCmp('pagingToolbar').pageSize=newlimit;
```

But it does not help

Answer (score 0):

specify segment of data you want to load using params

store.load({
    params:{
        start:0,
        limit: itemsPerPage
    }
});

Comment: Thanks! I know that. But I'm asking about loadData function and not about load

Answer (score 0):

try `grid.getStore().pageSize = newlimit`. the store is shared with the paging toolbar.